# Where is apache web root directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, lamp

On Ubuntu Trusty, which is the `apache` root directory for web pages?

Comment: Thanks every one i simply was looking for the Ubuntu equivalent of the htdocs folder in windows.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The default document root for Apache is `/var/www/` (before Ubuntu 14.04) or `/var/www/html/` (Ubuntu 14.04 and later).

See the file `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` for some explanation on how the Apache configuration on Ubuntu is done.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, 13.10 was the first release to have apache2.4 by default. Thus it's `/var/www/html/` for 13.10 as well. It doesn't really matter, since 13.10 has long been unsupported.